# How to monitor CPU voltage for a Dell XPS15 9550 (Skylake i5-6300HQ) under Linux

Tags: monitoring, cpu, sensors

I've been using Linux for 99% of the time on my Dell XPS15 9550. It has an Intel i5-6300HQ (Skylake) CPU.

On Windows, I can monitor the voltage of the CPU using a plethora of different software: Intel XTU, HWinfo, CPU-Z, AIDA64 and many more. On Linux, my only shot seems to be with LM-Sensors... which unfortunately does not find any voltage sensor even with a deep search from `sensors-detect`. Other tools such as `turbostat`, `powerstat` or `i7z` also do not read CPU voltages.

No voltage sensor is found by any of the generic monitoring software I have tried (such as KSysGuard).

Is there any way to read Skylake CPU voltages (directly from the CPU) in Linux, something that is so trivial in Windows? Is there a module which I am not loading, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out `i7z` actually does report the Vcore on my system. My terminal was simply not wide enough to show the last column, which was indeed Vcore.

So a partial answer is: use `i7z`. However, it would be even better to have this data collected by `lm-sensors` too. Currently it does not, so most monitoring programs that use `lm-sensors` as backend do not show the data.